Is replacing a bad habit with a good one more effective than stopping the bad habit alone?
Replacing bad habits with good ones is commonplace advice. However, I have seen this claim repeated on reputable sites, suggesting that there is evidence behind it, but no evidence is provided:
American Heart Association:

Research shows that replacing a bad behavior with a good one is more
effective than stopping the bad behavior alone. The new behavior
“interferes” with the old habit and prevents your brain from going
into autopilot.

National Institutes of Health:

One way to kick bad habits is to actively replace unhealthy routines
with new, healthy ones. Some people find they can replace a bad habit,
even drug addiction, with another behavior, like exercising. “It
doesn’t work for everyone,” Volkow says. “But certain groups of
patients who have a history of serious addictions can engage in
certain behaviors that are ritualistic and in a way compulsive—such as
marathon running—and it helps them stay away from drugs. These
alternative behaviors can counteract the urges to repeat a behavior to
take a drug.”

Healthline:

You might have an easier time breaking a habit if you replace the
unwanted behavior with a new behavior, instead of simply trying to
stop the unwanted behavior.

CNBC article:

Breaking a “bad” habit isn’t an easy feat, but replacing an activity
that you’re hoping to change with a healthier alternative can make the
process a bit less challenging.

Some book:

Learn why you cannot simply “quit” a bad habit, but must replace that
bad habit with a new habit to experience success.

This site and this one both mention a study by Adriaanse et al (2011) that supposedly supports this claim. However, this single study did not compare replacing a habit with just stopping it. Rather, it tested whether implementation intention (a planning strategy) affects reaction times related to goal words.
While adopting good habits is likely good advice regardless of its effects on bad habits, I'm skeptical that bad habits are decreased more effectively by replacement than by cessation alone.

I'm concerned that this may better fit on (possibly) [psychology.se] rather than here. It varies quite a bit between individuals, addicts, for example I know there is data on this. Not sure how this can be tested without getting specific about the habit and about the segment of the population involved.

If you post the question on psychology.se, then adding research that you should find using the search term "cross addiction" would be a good idea. There's an introduction for you.

@ArnonWeinberg a google search shows many references of America's NIH about replacement activities for addictions. Didn't you find any of them? Here is one

@WeatherVane: I'm not sure it qualifies "Vinyasa yoga or a general health and wellness program (contact control)". Both are activities. (Maybe the 'wellness' program bored people out of their minds.) However, one might find control groups where doing nothing was the control.

TBH a potential issue with this Q is what qualifies as a habit. E.g. does going to some Yoga for a while qualify as a habit, even if after the study period is over most participants stop doing Yoga, so it doesn't become a habit for them? And what exactly is replacement. One presumably can't do much Yoga [in the same amount of time] instead of taking a smoking break at work, for instance.

It's certainly good advice. Just quitting a habit leaves a void. One needs something to fill the void. I think it is going to be difficult to prove that the claim is being believed, popularly.

@NigelJ: That's begging the question. Is there evidence that "filling the void" is more effective than just giving up the bad habit?

@Oddthinking D'you know what axioms are?

@Oddthinking Can you say why you doubt NigelJ's assertion? I thought that was almost too obvious to bother stating…

@Oddthinking Since you took it upon yourself to censor what you clearly did not understand, can you point me to SE Skeptics' procedures for complaint and censure?

We go by evidences statements rather than assertions, it's a valid challenge not requiring justification. @RobbieGoodwin

@JiminyCricket. Why are you addressing that to me, please? Your rules seem to suggest mine was a valid challenge not requiring justification. Is that what you meant?

I was just commenting on your comment directed to Oddthinking. If you need to know about dissatisfactions or issues that you've not been able to resolve by reading the help centre or meta - or by asking a question on meta, then you should consider using the "contact us" button at the bottom of any page and explain to staff what the issue is, ensuring to present evidence, not just a version from memory - that would be the go-to place for strong complaints about moderator abuse. (Beware the standard a complaint needs to reach is high). @RobbieGoodwin

Please excuse the run-on sentence, bad habit of mine. @RobbieGoodwin

Thanks, Jiminy Cricket

Hi @RobbieGoodwin: Welcome to Skeptics! Yes, the Contact link at the bottom of the page is how to escalate reports of mod abuse. You seem to have misunderstood a few aspects of what I said and what this site is about. I recommend reading that Welcome link. I will also respond to your questions here.

@RobbieGoodwin: Yes, of course I know what axioms are. Your question comes across as quite rude. I also know that it is begging the question to simply assume the conclusion as a premise. The reason I do not simply accept NigelJ's assertion is because that is the issue at hand. The OP doubts that a good habit "fills the void" of a bad habit, and that it is more effective to deliberately adopt a good habit in an effort to give up a bad habit. We are looking for evidence in an answer box, not just an assertion in a comment.

As for "censoring" what I "clearly did not understand", @RobbieGoodwin is referring to a downvoted answer of his that I deleted in accordance with policy because it was entirely theoretical in nature. Also, as I said in a comment on the answer: This seems to be based on a misunderstanding of the claim. The question isn't "Is it better to have a good habit than a bad habit?" It is "Is starting non-bad habit a good way to help permanently give up a bad habit?"

@Oddthinking Sorry; the Answer I Posted was not at all, let alone 'entirely theoretical in nature…'
Also, as should be obvious to all readers here, the main 'misunderstanding of the claim' remains yours.
The wording 'Is starting non-bad habit a good way to help permanently give up a bad habit' is your own, not OP Arnon Weinberg's.
I suggest your paraphrasing is unnecessary; at best confusing, and in no way helpful.

As suggested earlier, our meta site is a better place for a specific question about a specific question and the way it was handled or how to improve it. You've got the rep points to be able to post there, why not formulate your argument in a less limited way than comments allow?

@RobbieGoodwin: You answer had no empirical evidence, no references, invented a theoretical mathematical model of habits as -1 or +1, and attacked the question as being unworthy of the site. It had 3 downvotes (from others), it was flagged, and a commenter tried several times to explain the problem to you. It wasn't an answer suitable for this site. I suggest reading the OP's references to understand what they are claiming or moving on.
